# Add style to node of a tree ("li")

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following tree- http://jsfiddle.net/anirbankundu/wzEBW/

This tree can have n number of nodes. When user hovers over a single node  the node background color needs to changed. Basically a hover class needs to be added to the li. At any point only one node can be highlighted.The style that I am applying it is basically adding the li's subsequent children.  (See the fiddle link)

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrapped the "a" elements around "div":

```
<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.toggleChildren, text: showChildren() ? ' - ' : ' + '"></a>
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a> 
        </div>
        <ul data-bind="visible: showChildren, template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: children }"></ul>
    </li>
 </script>
```

and make a little change to the css:

```
li ul li div:hover {
    background-color: #C0DDF0;
}​
```

it's seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/twTcw/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can "undo" the highlighting on the child nodes:

```
li:hover {
   background: red;
}

li:hover li {
   background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got it working, but this is a bit simpler and may cause less randomness if you add levels in the future:

`li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #C0DDF0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In CSS use

```
ul li ul li.hover {
    background-color: #C0DDF0;
}
```

instead of

```
ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #C0DDF0;
}
```

And in JavaScript (jQuery) write:

```
$("ul li ul li","#pnlDestinations").live("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover").siblings("li").removeClass("hover");
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

This will achieve cross-browser compatibility of the script. Please see the updated script [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wzEBW/1/). As your example script does not contain any sub list it will not work now. But if you like to see a working version for demonstration then find it from [hear](http://jsfiddle.net/wzEBW/5/).